# Overwrite or update Android playlist database from Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, playlist

I'm writing a small app that retrieves all items in an Android created playlist, with the ability to sort the list by a certain order.  What I want to do is have this sort actually save back to the database, or update the playlist file.  Being relatively new to Android development, I'm not sure what the proper approach is to this.

Here's my code:

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.List;

public class PlaylistSongActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String SONG_ID_KEY  = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID;
    final String SONG_ARTIST_KEY  = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST;
    final String SONG_ALBUM_KEY = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM;
    final String SONG_TITLE_KEY  = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE;
    final String SONG_TRACK_NO_KEY = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TRACK;
    final String CASE_INSENTIVE = " COLLATE NOCASE ";
    final String[] PLAYLIST_QUERY_COLUMNS = {SONG_ID_KEY, SONG_ARTIST_KEY, SONG_TITLE_KEY, SONG_ALBUM_KEY, SONG_TRACK_NO_KEY};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist);
        // Spinner values
        final Spinner playlistSettingsDropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.playlistSettingsDropdown);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.playlist_settings_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        playlistSettingsDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        playlistSettingsDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                sortGrid(pos);
            }

            public void setId(int pos) {
                playlistSettingsDropdown.setSelection(pos);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // Another interface callback
            }
        });

        // Song grid
        ListView playlistSongsView = getSongGrid();
        final Cursor playlistSongs = createPlaylistCursor(null);
        PlaylistSongCursor playlistSongsAdapter = new PlaylistSongCursor(playlistSongsView.getContext(), playlistSongs);
        playlistSongsView.setAdapter((playlistSongsAdapter));
    }

    public void sortGrid(int sortType) {
        ListView songGrid = getSongGrid();
        PlaylistSongCursor songGridAdapter = (PlaylistSongCursor) songGrid.getAdapter();
        String sort = SONG_ARTIST_KEY + CASE_INSENTIVE + " ASC," +
                SONG_ALBUM_KEY + CASE_INSENTIVE + " ASC," +
                SONG_TRACK_NO_KEY + " ASC";
        switch (sortType) {
            case 1:
                sort = SONG_ARTIST_KEY + CASE_INSENTIVE + " DESC," +
                        SONG_ALBUM_KEY + CASE_INSENTIVE + " DESC," +
                        SONG_TRACK_NO_KEY + " DESC";
        }
        songGridAdapter.changeCursor(createPlaylistCursor(sort));
    }

    public ListView getSongGrid() {
        return (ListView) findViewById((R.id.playlistItems));
    }

    public Uri getPlaylistUri() {
        int playlistId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("playlistId");
        return MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistId);
    }

    public Cursor createPlaylistCursor(String sort) {
        return getContentResolver().query(getPlaylistUri(), null, null, null, sort);
    }
}
```

So I get the list's ID from my passed intent, grab its URI from the `MediaStore` package, and then use the URI to get the Cursor from the query using `ContentProvider`... this all works, the playlist songs show up just fine, and my sorting works as well (although, I'd welcome any critique on what I'm doing).  The problem is how would I use the cursor to save back to the database, so it persists to other music apps? (BlackPlayer has this ability with its Sort by Artist - Album option)

I was thinking of a few ways, but I'm not entirely sure how to execute them:

- Do something with `ContentValues` (retrieved from
  [`DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#cursorRowToContentValues(android.database.Cursor,%20android.content.ContentValues)))
- Use [`getWritableDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()) somehow... not sure how to retrieve the DB itself
- Overwrite the `File`, but because it's a `URI` and `SQLite` file, I wasn't sure how to save a `File` like this... does it have to be in a special format?

Does anyone have any insight?

**UPDATE**

I started going down the route of using bulkInsert, but it appears it doesn't insert the `ContentValues[]` into my DB... this definitely deletes my rows, and my `retVal` contains the number of items to insert, it just doesn't insert...

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ListView songGrid = getSongGrid();
            PlaylistSongCursor songGridAdapter = (PlaylistSongCursor) songGrid.getAdapter();
            Cursor myCursor = songGridAdapter.getCursor();
            ContentValues[] retVal = new ContentValues[myCursor.getCount()];
            ContentValues map;
            int i = 0;
            if(myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    map = new ContentValues();
                    DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues(myCursor, map);
                    retVal[i++] = map;
                } while(myCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // Empties db
            getContentResolver().delete(getPlaylistUri(), null, null);
            // Logs 2 (as that's how many items are in my list)
            Log.d("BLA", String.valueOf(retVal.length));
            final int retInt = getContentResolver().bulkInsert(getPlaylistUri(), retVal);
            // Logs 0
            Log.d("DONE", String.valueOf(retInt));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an incredible amount of help from [qbeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2870138/qbeck), I was able to figure this one out.  I was missing some key things... in order to save back to the playlist's `Uri`, I had to make sure it used the same columns its schema has... looking at the `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.*` attributes, I could sort of glean what the table's schema's actual fields were... Android Studio made these keys in bold, but looking back on it now, I think that's what [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.html#constants) is telling me.

I used this information to figure out that I needed to update the [`PLAY_ORDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.html#PLAY_ORDER) value, so I first started down the route of `ContentProvider.update`, but for each row, this took quite some time for large lists, and I reached some sort of Cursor undefined error.  I then tried deleting all rows in the DB and doing a [`ContentProvider.bulkInsert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#bulkInsert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues[])), which was quite a bit quicker AND did what I needed it to do... now my lists appear in this sorted order in other music apps.

```
getSaveButton().setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Cursor myCursor = createPlaylistCursor(sort);
        int i = 0;
        if(myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            Uri playListUri = getPlaylistUri();
            ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[myCursor.getCount()];
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            do {
                ContentValues map = new ContentValues();
                map.put(PLAY_ORDER_KEY, Long.valueOf(i + 1));
                map.put(AUDIO_ID_KEY, myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AUDIO_ID_KEY)));
                values[i++] = map;
            } while(myCursor.moveToNext());
            contentResolver.delete(playListUri, null, null);
            contentResolver.bulkInsert(playListUri, values);
            Log.d("BLA", "done");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So your problem is fixed? Am i right? Accept your answer if so.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I tried accepting it last night, but it said I had to wait 14 hours before accepting.  Thanks for all your help, sir!

Comment: i have used this approach but in case of larg data it taks alot of time

Comment: Yeah, this never was optimized to be the most performant... I just needed to get it working.  I'm sure you could find ways to make it much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Check the official documentation for [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Modifications). Basically `ContentProvider` hides database so you can communicate with it using URI (and `ContentValues` if needed), but not with database directly.

```
//Create empty values
ContentValues values= new ContentValues();

//put all you want to update
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER, sort);

//call update method on ContentResolver
int rows = getContentResolver().update(
    getPlaylistUri(), //uri to modify
    values, //new values for 
    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID + "=?", //selection clause 
    new String[] {String.valueOf(playlistId)} //selection args
);
```

I assume that `query` should sort your playlist according to this column if you won't specify sort parameter

```
return getContentResolver().query(getPlaylistUri(), 
                      PLAYLIST_QUERY_COLUMNS, null, null, null);
```

according to `ContentResolver` doc:

> String: How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause
>   (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default
>   sort order, which may be unordered.

There is also another option - create your own database, which will store playlists' IDs with `order by` clause, which you can maintain by yourself (i.e. you have more complex logic in your project regarding playlists or sorting etc.).

**EDIT**

Are you sure `myCursor` (which is mapped to `retVal`) contains all needed data for insert? You should make sure that **all required columns persist in content values for every row you want to insert according to URI**. You retrieved ([MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.html)) URI with desired columns for your cursor. But columns you've selected come from inherited `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns`. It's fine for `query` since `ContentProvider` may just join some audio tables to get those for you. But now you want to insert data (according to URI) into `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members`, but you don't specify any of its columns since all you've got are data from linked tables (`AudioColumns`).

- `query` - select whatever you want to select from offered columns
- `update` - put values you want to update for rows according to selection
- `insert` - provide all required values for table

And the last thing, unfortunately you can't force 3rd party providers to respect `DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER`. You can try to clear caches but I doubt that it will help.

Comment: So here's the thing... whenever I open a music app, I think the playlist sort order defaults to how the songs were added to the playlist itself, and because I haven't seen a music app that allows you to sort on a specific column, I want to actually replace the playlist with this new sorted list.  I feel like this approach won't do what I'm asking... am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: The default sort order [according to doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.html#DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER)  is set to `playlist_id`, which seems to me not determined (playlist ID is the same for every song in the list). Updating `DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER` should lead to desired sorting after querying with `null` for `sortOrder`. So you don't need to replace playlist but only `DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER`. Seems fine fore me, but I can check in the free time.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  Excellent... I will give this a try when I get home.  Thanks!

Comment: All right, this definitely seems to work, but unfortunately, it looks like music apps (tested BlackPlayer, Rocket Player, and a playlist backup app) do not respect using the default sort order.  I also rebooted the phone just to make sure.  This answer is so close... I'll keep picking at it.

Comment: see update in description if you get a chance, please.

Comment: Ah yes, you're on the same thinking that I was... so I actually ended up taking off the columns and specified null instead (which I read returns all columns... or am I reading wrong?).  Although, I didn't try this with the `update` way that you provided... I'll retry that.  Does my `bulkInsert` look like it should work though?

Comment: For `query` select columns you want, for `update` specify columns you want to change, for `insert` provide columns linked with URI. Do you have you project on github or somewhere I can clone it and look into it?

Comment: Unfortunately, my github profile is just one giant mess of code... so I uploaded the src dir to my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmjgrx3n6hnt4hu/main.zip?dl=0).  Think I got all necessary files... let me know if there's anything else you need.  Thanks for doing this!

Comment: It appears you're right... my `cursorRowToContentValues` dumps a lot of columns to the ContentValues, which, upon insertion, fails because that DB does not contain all of those columns.  If I pare it down to just `AUDIO_ID` and `PLAY_ORDER`, insertion works.  However, `bulkInsert` doesn't appear to be implemented, and unfortunately, using these 2 columns doesn't fix my issue... I think I need `DATE_ADDED`, but I can't seem to update that... I wish I could see the DB's schema.